# Nested Python Loops - How to create a reversed triangle

Tags: python

```
size = 3
for line in range (1, size +1):
    for asterisk in range(1, line +1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
```

This code produces

```
*
**
***
```

I have been asked to alter the code so that it reverses the asterisk 'triangle' like so:

```
  *
 **
***
```

I can't figure out how to do it and I'm really struggling to understand what the loops are doing and how I would alter the code to produce the correct triangle.

I'm offered a hint of: "spaces can be produced using `print('  ', end = '')`
and also: "Notice that we want the first line to start to start with two spaces, the second with a space and the last with none. We can get this value in each case by subtracting the number of the line from the size of the triangle (3) and adding 1"

As far as I understand the second point, it should be *size - line + 1* , right? What I don't understand is how to build this into the loop. As far as I can understand, I need to change the second nested loop but, I can't for life of me figure out how as every attempt I have made results in something like this:

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
```

Comment: Judging by your bottom pyramid, you are putting spaces in between your asterisks. To create the 2nd pyramid, you need to put all the spaces before your asterisks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write "I don't understand is how to build this into the loop" that is because printing the spaces should not be in your innermost loop. You want to print spaces on each line but not within the asterisks, so you want the loop for spaces to be inside your overall loop but *before* your asterisk loop (rather than inside it). Here is one way to get it to work.

```
size = 3
for line in range (1, size +1):
    for space in range(1, size - line + 1):
        print(' ', end='')
    for asterisk in range(1, line +1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
```

On another, less important note, your ranges have many "+1"s in them since you start the ranges at 1. It is more pythonic to start at zero, and that will simplify your code as well, though those "+1"s do not all go away and we add one "-1". So you can do it this way:

```
size = 3
for line in range(size):
    for space in range(size - line - 1):
        print(' ', end='')
    for asterisk in range(line + 1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
```

Also note that you do not actually need all those loops--Python has other ways to accomplish those goals. For one thing, you can multiply a string by a constant to get repetitions of the string. In other words, `'*' * 5` results in `'*****'`. This gives you:

```
size = 3
for line in range(size):
    print(' ' * (size - line - 1), end='')
    print('*' * (line + 1))
```

or perhaps even better,

```
size = 3
for line in range (1, size + 1):
    print(' ' * (size - line) + '*' * (line))
```

(I moved the "+1"s there to be more clear.) You could also use the `join()` method to remove that outer loop, but I'll stop here.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time! That's answered my question perfectly!